# Can I omit "await" of Clients.All.SendAsync() in .NET Core SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, async-await, signalr

```
        public async Task GetLiveCandleStick(string param)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", param);
        }
```

Please consider the above code.

Almost all of the tutorial `await` `Clients.xxx.SendAsync` methods. However, I find that it works fine even I take away the `await` keyword. Then what is the point of using `await`? (I have seen a thread explaned that `await` is not meant to "wait until client receive the message...")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case, you don't need to use `await`

Comment: Take a look at this: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) *"I recommend keeping the async and await keywords around, except for a few scenarios."*

Comment: Please consider ASP.NET Architect's (David Fowler) [suggestion](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-asyncawait-over-directly-returning-task) as well

Comment: Use should use `await` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0 `Use await when calling asynchronous methods that depend on the hub staying alive. For example, a method such as Clients.All.SendAsync(...) can fail if it's called without await and the hub method completes before SendAsync finishes.`

Answer (score 4):

By omitting the `await` keyword, the method would become fire-and-forget; this is almost never the right thing to do, as you would have no way of knowing that the `Task` had completed.

Another issue is exception handling. If an exception occurs when you call `SendAsync`, it is placed on the `Task` rather than being thrown directly, and would simply be garbage collected without using `await`.

Having said this, if your `GetLiveCandleStick` method is a simple wrapper as you suggest, it would be slightly more efficient to simply return the `Task` from `SendAsync` rather than create a new one using `async`:

```
public Task GetLiveCandleStick(string param)
{
    return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", param);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Johnathan Barclay, you make it so clear... but I still have an uncertainty...   What is the mean by "`task` had completed"? Does it mean that until the client received the message and acknowledge the server? or just simply mean that the message has been sent out?

Comment: @mannok From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#call-hub-methods-from-client) _The `SendAsync` method returns a `Task` which completes when the message has been sent to the server. No return value is provided since this `Task` doesn't wait until the server method completes._

Comment: @mannok Also: _Any exceptions thrown on the client while sending the message produce a faulted Task. Use `await` and `try...catch` syntax to handle send errors._

Comment: Yes, good point on error handling. But for SendAsync, I still don't get it as the explanation that you have provided is about "client calling server", Different between `InvokeAsync` and `SendAsync` is whether to wait the method return or not. How about "server calling client"? i.e. When will `Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", param)` be "resolved"? i.e. once the message reach client? once the client function return?  or anything else? many thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this case only, you don't need to use `await` - nothing else is happening after `SendAsync` so there's no need to await. Awaiting on `GetLiveCandleStick` would behave the same as awaiting on `SendAsync`. You could convert this method to :

```
public Task GetLiveCandleStick(string param)=> Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", param);
```

Tutorials use `await` because quite often there *is* code after `SendAsync`, that should be executed after SignalR enqueues the message.

You may want to add error handling in case SignalR throws for example, or ensure a `Begin` message is enqueued after an `End` message in a tight loop. Having an `await` even for a single statement method can be useful for debugging too.

Finally, good tutorials shouldn't introduce unrelated concepts as this can easily lead to confusion. A SignalR tutorial isn't the best place for explaining the `await` state machine, or when `await` can be skipped. Unfortunately, too many examples in `learn.microsoft.com` try to put everything into a single page, resulting in quite a bit of confusion.

Comment: It's also important that nothing is happening _before_ `SendAsync`. By removing the `async` keyword, any exceptions that are thrown before `SendAsync` is called would be thrown directly rather than being placed on the `Task`.

Comment: Thank you @Panagiotis Kanavos, May I know what will SignalR do to enqueue a message? If it is just a message queue adding action then there is no reason to make is as a task...   and in fact what are we waiting for by using this function with an `await`?

Comment: According to the documentation `Use await when calling asynchronous methods that depend on the hub staying alive. For example, a method such as Clients.All.SendAsync(...) can fail if it's called without await and the hub method completes before SendAsync finishes.`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @JamieRRytlewski unless you don't have to await. This isn't about SignalR. When the only call in the method is a single asynchronous call you can just return the task returned from that call.  Awaiting has to go all the way to the top, so `GetLiveCandleStick` itself has to be awaited, otherwise the *entire* chain is fire-and-forget. Even if you used `await Clients.All.SendAsync()` you'd still get a failure if you didn't await `GetLiveCandleStick()` as well

Answer (score -1):

The keyword "await" is for async methods. It's smarter than "wait", it's async wait!
This means that wait the return of message during exec the code until the result is necessary used. So You don't have to use Thread.Wait in a line of code, but the compiler place the wait in the right position. In this case the method that call the await is async, so the wait of Clients.All.SendAsync is out of function.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. Given that the method already returns a `Task` and the results of `SendAsync` aren't used, is there any reason to `await`? There isn't